# OraSQL Select Command where multiple entry have same data

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table (We call it t_table) with the columns "DATE" and "TIME" (There are more columns, but only these are interesting).

I want my SELECT command to show me only entrys, that have more than one entry with the same combination of "DATE" and "TIME".

example:

```
Entry           | DATE     | TIME
1               |   1/1/14 | 8:00 
2               |   1/1/14 | 8:00
3               |   2/1/14 | 8:10
4               |   3/1/14 | 8:10
5               |   3/1/14 | 8:10
```

Should only display me the rows `(1+2) + (4+5)` because those entrys have the same combination of DATE/TIME in more than one entry.

I'm quite new to SQL so i am relly thankful for every help - Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Nishant for cleaning that example table - i failed there :)

Comment: Can you add your required output too(as rows) ?

Comment: Output should be the full content of the rows mentioned (row 1,2 and 4,5)

Comment: @Luke always a pleasure.. i am a bit confused with the output though.. if you are expecting that the select statement should display those columns which have same value of DATE + TIME then the output should only be (1+2)+(4+5) ??

Comment: You are right, im sorry! Just got up and started work. Guess i should sleep earlier when i have to work the next day. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the combination of data(other than the `id` here) in the table again using `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 'X' FROM TABLE B
 WHERE A.DATE = B.DATE
  AND A.TIME = B.TIME
  AND A.ID <> B.ID)
```

> [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/faf77/2)

Comment: Havent tried this one out, because the one above worked for me. But thank you!

Comment: @Luke I am just curious, the other answer will make a wrong join and thus duplicated duplicates!

Comment: I noticed it takes qute a while to execute.. trying urs now x.x

Comment: I tried 
"SELECT A.* FROM [TABLE] A WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM [TABLE] B WHERE A.DATE = B.DATE AND A.TIME = B.TIME and a.strID NOT LIKE b.strID)"

My Programm tells me the following;
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."
Notice, that easy commands like "select * from table where id = 2" are working

Comment: @Luke `[TABLE]` is not valid syntax, did you try without that. By the way , what IDE or client you use?

Comment: Dont worry, the ´[TABLE]´ is replaced with the correct table name. I just have to hide the correct names because im not sure what i am allowed to give to public :-) 

I'm working with vb in Visual Studio

Comment: Okay i got it working now! Your command was fully correct, im sorry!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the sequence you run the `SQL` and the DataReader. Definitely, this is not because of the SQL. This is such a simple `SQL`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, it might work with this:

```
Select a.id,b.id from t_table a, t_table b where a.date=b.date and a.time = b.time;
```